# How to test if fields of my select query are null and then display the desired result in one command?

Tags: mysql

I have a select query with many columns and I don't want to check if the fields are null one by one.
The if satatement is always the same for all the fields.

Is there a solution to test all the fields at one time.

This is the not desired solution :

```
SELECT IF(clo1 = null, '', col1), IF(clo2 = null, '', col2), IF(clo3 = null, '', col3), IF(clo4 = null, '', col4),  .....
FROM my_mytable
```